# Problem with adding new folders android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

When I try to add new folder in android studio, weird thing happens. Android studio "glues" the empty folders and it looks like in the picture. I don't want this to happen, how to disable this unintuitive behaviour?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Click settings icon in `Project Files` view and uncheck `Compact Directories`.

Comment: It's just a display thing, once you know what it does you'll probably prefer it! Saves opening `com`, then `java`, then `yourpackagename` etc

Comment: @cactustictacs yes in some cases. But what if I want to add new class in "com" folder? If this is enabled, when I add new class to folder it goes directly to "yourpackagename" since it is shrinked with java folder. I definitely understand benefit that you said but this is downfall in my opinion. How to solve this... enable/disable this feature every time you need to add new class like this? (if so that is little bit tiring)

Comment: @Kratos why would you want to add a *class* in the `com` directory? That would put it in the `com` package, and broadly speaking, your whole project lives within the `yourpackagename` package (including subpackages / subfolders). That's why if you use the `New Class` menu option it puts it in `yourpackagename` by default (and if you name it `stuff.NewClass` it'll end up in `com.wow.yourpackagename.stuff.NewClass`, a subpackage). You *can* uncheck `Compact Middle Packages` and click `com` and add a class in there *if you really want*, but the default behaviour is what's useful to most people

Comment: @cactustictacs "com" is just an example for the same situation that happens to me in my question (adding class to the shrinked folder). Ofc there are never classes in com folder :D. Ok in the situation that happens in my case (you can see on my picuture) the best thing is to uncheck "Compact Middle Packages", add class to repository folder and than check "Compact Middle Packages" again since it is useful for better transparency of packages. Got it!

Comment: It's not that it's more transparent, it just collapses the folders with nothing in them except the next folder, so it's less clicking and the view's a bit cleaner. And sorry, I was wrong about the `New Class` behaviour - the name you type is relative to *the current file open in the editor*, unless you open the `Project` panel and right-click a directory to get the `New` menu (or use the keyboard, *Ctrl+Alt+Insert*). So the way you're *expected* to add them in your case is to navigate to `data`, open the `New Class` dialog, and type `repository.DogFact` or whatever. Use whichever you like!

Comment: Deal I got it. Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you open this pop up and remove tick?

[image]

Comment: Thank you short and precise answer, appreciate it!